# WP8.1 in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using Xamarin with Visual Studio. Whenever I create a new Blank Project (PCL), it adds 3 projects along with the Portable solution: Android, iOS, WinPhone 8.0.

Now what I want is WP8.1. I tried selecting it as a target, but the project isnt created. If I choose "Retarget to WP8.1", it converts to WP Silverlight 8.1.

Can anyone suggest a good cross platform tutorial for Xamarin? All I found are about about creating Android app using C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin Forms did not support WP8.1 till April 29, 2015. So maybe the version you have installed is not the newest or they did not update the project template yet. Check it out here:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/windows/

Tutorials for Xamarin Forms can be found on their webpage:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/

**Edit:** New Project does not automatically add WP8.1 project. You have to manually add it and configure it like this:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/windows/getting-started/#pcl

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/windows/getting-started/phone/

Comment: No, I have the updated version. Just read that WP8.1 is not automatically added in the new project. We have to manually add and configure it.

Also, the I had already seen the tutorials on Xamarin's website, but the thing is I'm not able to execute their samples, some pacakge issues, havent been able to solve those.

Comment: Can you tell me how do I configure the manually added WP8.1 project for Xamarin?

Comment: Have you checked out this already?
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/windows/getting-started/

Comment: Great! Would be nice if you could accept my answer!

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting package errors for their samples? I tried "Enable NuGet Restore" still nothing.

Comment: Can you just combine my "WP8.1 is not automatically added in the new project" and your configuration link? Will select it as an answer